# Count rows in a Pandas group that meet certain criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add a column to a DataFrame that indicates how many times the customer has included more than 10 items in an order.

My code currently looks like:

```py
import pandas as pd


my_data = {'customer_id' : ['101A', '101A', '104B', '102A', '101A', '104B', '102A', '104B', '101A', '102A' ],
      'date' : ['20120321','20120201','20120123','20111218','20111209','20111127','20111118','20111012','20111001','20110921'],
      'invoice_amt' : [654.76, 234.45, 99.45, 767.63, 124.76, 346.87, 652.65, 765.21, 275.76, 532.21 ],
      'no_line_items' : [19, 24, 6, 2, 6, 4, 18, 10, 18, 8]}


data_df = pd.DataFrame(my_data).sort_index(by='date',ascending=True)
```

Figure out the max number of items per invoice per customer:

```
data_df['max_line_items'] = data_df.groupby('customer_id')['no_line_items'].transform(lambda x: x.max())
```

Figure out the number of invoices per customer where the items greater than or equal to 10:

```
data_df['no_vip_invoices'] = data_df.groupby('customer_id')[data_df['no_line_items']>10].transform(lambda x: x.count())
```

My ideal output would be:

```py
  customer_id      date  invoice_amt  no_line_items  max_line_items   no_vip_invoices
9        102A  20110921       532.21              8              18         1
8        101A  20111001       275.76             18              24         3
7        104B  20111012       765.21             10              10         0
6        102A  20111118       652.65             18              18         1
5        104B  20111127       346.87              4              10         0
4        101A  20111209       124.76              6              24         3
3        102A  20111218       767.63              2              18         1
2        104B  20120123        99.45              6              10         0
1        101A  20120201       234.45             24              24         3
0        101A  20120321       654.76             19              24         3
```

Currently getting the error

```py
KeyError: 'Columns not found: True'
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using `lambda`

This gives you the  desired output dataframe:

```
grouped = data_df.groupby('customer_id')
data_df['max_line_items'] = grouped['no_line_items'].transform(lambda x: x.max())
data_df['no_vip_invoices'] = grouped['no_line_items'].transform(lambda x: len(x[x>10]))


print(data_df.to_string())
```

Output:

```
  customer_id      date  invoice_amt  no_line_items  max_line_items  no_vip_invoices
9        102A  20110921       532.21              8              18                1
8        101A  20111001       275.76             18              24                3
7        104B  20111012       765.21             10              10                0
6        102A  20111118       652.65             18              18                1
5        104B  20111127       346.87              4              10                0
4        101A  20111209       124.76              6              24                3
3        102A  20111218       767.63              2              18                1
2        104B  20120123        99.45              6              10                0
1        101A  20120201       234.45             24              24                3
0        101A  20120321       654.76             19              24                3
```

### Using `def`

If you don't like or don't want `lambda`, you can always use normal functions:

```
def by_max(group):
    """Group by maximum.
    """
    return group.max()

def by_len(group):
    """Group by length greater 10.
    """
    return len(group[group>10])

data_df['max_line_items'] = grouped['no_line_items'].transform(by_max)
data_df['no_vip_invoices'] = grouped['no_line_items'].transform(by_len)
```

The result is the same as above. One advantage of this approach is that you can use docstrings.
Furthermore, you can also use statements which is not possible with `lambda`.

Comment: You can always write a function using `def` instead of using `lambda`. Maybe this makes things clearer.

Comment: Thanks Mike ... Not sure how I'd apply a function in this way though ... Any thoughts ?